How is one expected to write しゅっこう (出港) on Genkou Youshi? (原稿用紙)
Sorry if this is a basic question that has already been asked before. Genkou Youshi is the grid-like paper filled with boxes where Japanese is written in tategaki (vertically). My question is, how exactly would a word like しゅっこう (出港) be written, assuming it's written in hiragana and not kanji. For example, would しゅ occupy its own box? Or would し be in one box, and ゅ be in the next box? In which case, would the ゅ just be written small in the next box, or in the top-right of the next box? etc..
I guess, in general, I'm not sure how small characters are treated in tategaki.

原稿 means "manuscript", so you can get a rough idea of how to use it by looking at how typical Japanese texts are typeset in newspapers and magazines. Since small-tsu and similar characters occupy the same space as their normal-size equivalents, they each take up one box in 原稿用紙. In your case, しゅっこう uses five boxes. You can read more rules here.
